# Stepping Thread Group throws error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

The Test plan looks like this:

"MAIN SCRIPT " -Test Plan
            Stepping Thread Group

```
     Test Fragment
                  Include Controller - TT3.jmx
                  Include Controller - TT6.jmx

         "TT3" Thread Group
                    Does  some actions like Login,Select Projoect,Logout
                    No.Of Users  : 7
                   CSV Dats Config  file : For UserName & Password(TT3.csv)


         "TT6 End" Thread Group
                  Does  some actions like Login,Select Projoect,Logout
                    No.Of Users  : 2
                   CSV Dats Config  file : For UserName & Password(TT6.csv)
```

When  I exectued the test Throws below error:

`2015/04/03 12:40:11 INFO  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\JMETER\J_Scripts\TT3_UsingPort8080.jmx
2015/04/03 12:40:11 WARN  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: No Test Fragment was found in included Test Plan, returning empty HashTree
2015/04/03 12:40:11 INFO  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\JMETER\J_Scripts\TT6_UsingPort8080.jmx
2015/04/03 12:40:11 WARN  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: No Test Fragment was found in included Test Plan, returning empty HashTree
2015/04/03 12:40:12 INFO  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\JMETER\J_Scripts\TT3_UsingPort8080.jmx
2015/04/03 12:40:12 WARN  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: No Test Fragment was found in included Test Plan, returning empty HashTree
2015/04/03 12:40:12 INFO  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\JMETER\J_Scripts\TT6_UsingPort8080.jmx
2015/04/03 12:40:12 WARN  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: No Test Fragment was found in included Test Plan, returning empty HashTree
2015/04/03 12:41:33 INFO  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\JMETER\J_Scripts\TT3_UsingPort8080.jmx
2015/04/03 12:41:33 WARN  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: No Test Fragment was found in included Test Plan, returning empty HashTree
2015/04/03 12:41:33 INFO  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: loadIncludedElements -- try to load included module: E:\JMETER\J_Scripts\TT6_UsingPort8080.jmx
2015/04/03 12:41:33 WARN  - jmeter.control.IncludeController: No Test Fragment was found in included Test Plan, returning empty HashTree`

Could some one please advise me what am I missing?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the **Include Controller** in a right way, it is required to use **Test Fragment** in your Included test plan which is missing in the example provided by you. Without the use of **Test Fragment** your **Include Controller** will not get executed.

Please refer to the mentioned links for [Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) and [Test Fragment](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment).

https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments